change tzone on tibble column base R approach
I am able to change the time zone of a datetime column using lubridate syntax very easily, see df below.
But when I try to use a base R approach (df2 in reprex) using lapply and attr(x, "tzone) <- "" inside an anonymous function it just assigns an emtpy string to each variable.
I would normally use lubridate as it is much easier but trying to develop a function for a package and reduce reliance on dependancies and cannot find anywhere dealing with this specific issue. I am sure I am missing something simple having looked at it so long.
Thanks
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~DTSTART.TZID.Europe.London, ~DTEND.TZID.Pacific.Auckland, 
  "2023-04-06 12:00:00",       "2023-04-06 20:00:00",   
  "2023-04-06 14:00:00",       "2023-04-06 22:00:00"
)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    DTSTART.TZID.Europe.London = as.POSIXct(DTSTART.TZID.Europe.London, tz = "Europe/London"),
    DTEND.TZID.Pacific.Auckland = as.POSIXct(DTEND.TZID.Pacific.Auckland, tz = "Pacific/Auckland"),
    DTEND.TZID.Pacific.Auckland = lubridate::with_tz(DTEND.TZID.Pacific.Auckland, tzone = "")
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   DTSTART.TZID.Europe.London DTEND.TZID.Pacific.Auckland
#>   <dttm>                     <dttm>                     
#> 1 2023-04-06 12:00:00        2023-04-06 09:00:00        
#> 2 2023-04-06 14:00:00        2023-04-06 11:00:00

df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    DTSTART.TZID.Europe.London = as.POSIXct(DTSTART.TZID.Europe.London, tz = "Europe/London"),
    DTEND.TZID.Pacific.Auckland = as.POSIXct(DTEND.TZID.Pacific.Auckland, tz = "Pacific/Auckland")
  )
  
  
lapply(df2["DTEND.TZID.Pacific.Auckland"], function(x) {attr(x, "tzone") <- ""})
#> $DTEND.TZID.Pacific.Auckland
#> [1] ""

Created on 2024-04-30 with reprex v2.1.0

I think the problem lies in the way the function attr(x, "tzone") <- "" is used inside lapply. The function correctly changes the timezone attribute, but it doesn't return the modified datetime object. Instead, it returns the result of the assignment operation, which is "".
To effectively change the timezone for a datetime column using base R methods, you need to ensure that the function inside lapply returns the modified datetime object. This might work:
# Load necessary library
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

# Create the initial dataframe
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~DTSTART.TZID.Europe.London, ~DTEND.TZID.Pacific.Auckland, 
  "2023-04-06 12:00:00",       "2023-04-06 20:00:00",   
  "2023-04-06 14:00:00",       "2023-04-06 22:00:00"
)

# Convert strings to POSIXct with specified timezones
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    DTSTART.TZID.Europe.London = as.POSIXct(DTSTART.TZID.Europe.London, tz = "Europe/London"),
    DTEND.TZID.Pacific.Auckland = as.POSIXct(DTEND.TZID.Pacific.Auckland, tz = "Pacific/Auckland")
  )

# Correctly modify the timezone using base R
df2$DTEND.TZID.Pacific.Auckland <- lapply(df2["DTEND.TZID.Pacific.Auckland"], function(x) {
  attr(x, "tzone") <- "UTC"
  x
})

df2


you are absolutely correct! thank you
